# Python and postgis, trying to figure out data types

Tags: python, postgis

I have a simple sql I am running from python that gets all these items from a table (mostly the mpoly I am curious about).  Which is a geometry.

```
cur = self.db.cursor()
cur.execute('select St_AsText(ST_Centroid(mpoly)) from swsite_cesiumentity')
allEntities = cur.fetchall()
```

Then I can get the info out:

```
    print ' ***'
    print allEntities[0]
    print '----'
```

and it will give me:

`Row(st_astext='POINT(-87.266150008217 30.0857181963441)')`

That is well and good, but I try to use this data to then get all the points that are so far away from the above point and I do not know how to use the types I have in the sql query..  What I thought should work was:

```
for currentEntity in allEntities:
    print currentEntity
    cur2  = self.db.cursor()
    cur2.execute ('SELECT * FROM swsite_cesiumentity WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(mpoly, ST_GeomFromText(' + currentEntity.st_astext + ')) <= radius_mi * 1609.34)) from swsite_cesiumentity')
    list = cur2.fetchall()
    print list
```

It doesn't like what I am feeding the second sql statement:

```
pg.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "30.0857181963441"
LINE 1: ...ere(mpoly, ST_GeomFromText(POINT(-87.266150008217 30.0857181...
                                                             ^

C02RH2U9G8WM:ingest sth$
```

Comment: Does it drop quotes around WKT?

Comment: Why not use SQL to complete the entire process rather than 'this' sql to get the points into python then put it into 'that' sql...? PostGIS can do the whole thing, and you can use python to run the entire sql command and get the result?

Comment: I would love to do that, I am just trying learning postgis sql and so probably working harder not smarter on this.   I would love to make it simple. what i need to do is just really get a list of all points near one point and so on and so forth, I am trying to group polygons that are close  to eachother as one overall polygon

Comment: @user30184   not sure which you mean exactly here is the result of currentEntity.st_astext:  POINT(-87.266150008217 30.0857181963441)

Comment: @Codejoy if you have access to PGAdmin, use that as your GUI to PostGIS and the place you test your SQL - that exact SQL you use to select all those points can go into a Python select as you're trying to do - the results can be retrieved and interacted with as well... I then assume Python is being used to automate this for repetition later on?

Comment: Yes, it is to automatically lump these polygons as they are ingested as a file.. while retaining them as individual foot prints.  I will try to get pgadmin working with this.  I do have it, good idea. (I need to bone up on my sql kungfu)

Comment: @Codejoy once you figure out the SQL to get the 'geoprocessing' portion done - wrapping python around it is incredibly effective for what you're trying to do...

Comment: Thank you I will work on this, I have been learning a lot with this new postgis and it seems super powerful for these tasks.

Comment: Your error message shows ST_GeomFromText(POINT.... but it should be ST_GeomFromText('POINT... Something eats away the '

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41984861/327026)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
cur2.execute ('SELECT * FROM swsite_cesiumentity 
    WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(mpoly, ST_GeomFromText(' + 
    currentEntity.st_astext + ')) <= radius_mi * 1609.34)) 
    from swsite_cesiumentity')
```

needs escaped single quotes (') a around the WKT geometry. Currently, the geometry parser call is being formatted as,

```
ST_GeomFromText(POINT(-87.266150008217 30.0857181963441), ...
```

when it should be,

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-87.266150008217 30.0857181963441)', ...
```

You can fix it by enclosing the string in double quotes and using single quotes in the SQL:

```
cur2.execute ("SELECT * FROM swsite_cesiumentity 
    WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(mpoly, ST_GeomFromText('" +
    currentEntity.st_astext + "')) <= radius_mi * 1609.34)) 
    from swsite_cesiumentity")
```

(You might want to add an SRID for the second argument in `ST_GeomFromText` too.)